# Bash Mutt email with attachment error Can't stat : No such file or directory

Tags: bash, email, mutt

So i,ve read some other posts and tried out the answers, but i still keep running into this problem so i wanted to post a question here and see if anyone else had any other ideas. Keeping in mind i am pretty new to bash so i am iffy on whats available currently for what i,m looking for.

I am trying to automate a process that creates a file then sends it to me. All the above is fine, until i try to automatically email myself the file.

I have this line of code for it

```
echo "report" | mutt -- "$USEREMAIL" -s "report" -a "my_scripts/cid_reports/trb345432.csv"
```

When it tries to run this command it throws an error like

`Can't stat my_scripts/cid_reports/trb345432.csv: No such file or directory
my_scripts/cid_reports/trb345432.csv: unable to attach file.`

Any ideas on how i can fix this? I thought mutt was good to handle this, I am going to play with the mail feature and see if i can get any success with that.

The system looks to be running

```
Mutt 1.4.2.2i (2006-07-14)  
Copyright (C) 1996-2002 Michael R. Elkins and others.  
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -v
```

Comment: Your error message references a different file than the one you specify in your code.

Comment: Bah, i forgot to edit that to match, i shortened the code a little. The file names should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 9):

```
mutt -h

-a <file> [...] -- attach file(s) to the message
```

The list of files must be terminated with the "--" sequence, so,

```
echo "hello world" | mutt -s "title" -a /home/test.txt -- ***@**.com
```

You need to add "--".

Answer (score 3):

**SIMPLE ANSWER**

```
export EMAIL="sender_mail@example.com" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "Test Mail" -c "cc_recipient@example.com" -a /tmp/attachment.txt -- "recipient_mail@example.com" < /tmp/message.html
```

> Please use the following syntax while attaching files with 'mutt'.
>
> ```
> # mutt -a file -- user@domain
> ```
>
> For example;
>
> ```
> # mutt -a /tmp/test.txt -- john@abc.com
> ```
>
> Relevant snippets from the man page of mutt is given below.
>
> Raw
>   -a file [...]
>   Attach  a  file  to your message using MIME.  When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient addresses  with  "--"  is  mandatory,
>
> e.g.  mutt  -a image.jpg -- addr1 or mutt -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2.  The -a option must be placed at the end of command line options.

Ref: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43567

Answer (score 1):

The `no such file or directory` in general means that the file cannot be found. Because you're using a relative path, it might be that you are in a different directory?

If you type `cat my_scripts/cid_reports/trb345432.csv` from the same directory as you run the script, is the file there?

Or otherwise. if you use an absolute path (usually '/home/'uid'/my_scripts/cid_reports/trb345432.csv` but your path may be duifferent), does the script find the file?

(or should this have been a comment in stead of an answer, eventhough it tries to guide through finding the error?)

Comment: Thats the annoying part, IF i put in the file name itself IE 
my_scripts/cid_reports/trb345432.csv
its fine, If i reference it as a variable it throws that error.

Comment: So, your command is actually `echo "report" | mutt -- "$USEREMAIL" -s "report" -a "$some_filename"`? Try put, for debugging purposes, an `echo $some_filename ; ls $some_filename` before your call to MUTT.

Comment: Better yet, use `declare -p some_filename`.

Comment: So i,m not sure if i am doing it correctly for what you were asking, but when i did something like 
 FILE="~/my_scripts/cid_reports/file.csv"
                        
 declare -p FILE
                        
 ls $FILE
declare -- FILE="~/my_scripts/cid_reports/file.csv"
ls: ~/my_scripts/cid_reports/file.csv: No such file or directory

But if i manually run the ls ~/my_scripts/cid_reports/ or even cat ~/my_scripts/cid_reports/file.csv i will see the directory contents, and it will even spit out the file.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to Ljm Dullaart's answer, you're actually storing the file path in a variable, then using it something like this:

```
FILE="~/my_scripts/cid_reports/file.csv"
echo "report" | mutt -- "$USEREMAIL" -s "report" -a "$FILE"
```

If that's what you're doing, the problem is that `~` is in double-quotes, and therefore doesn't get expanded to the actual path to your home directory. Thus, it's looking for a sub directory literally named "~" under the current working directory, and not finding it. In order for `~` to be expanded to the path to your home directory, leave it and the following `/` unquoted, like this:

```
file=~/"my_scripts/cid_reports/file.csv"
echo "report" | mutt -- "$useremail" -s "report" -a "$file"
```

Note that I've also switched the variable names to lowercase. This is a best practice to avoid conflicts with the various environment variables that have special meanings; the special ones are all caps, so if you use lower- or mixed-case, you'll never accidentally trip over them.